How to throw error in addJavaScriptHandler of flutter_inappwebview
I have initialized a handler with addJavaScriptHandler and then I get params from callback function, I will need to return some data to the JS side by the callback function, But there is a possibility that I get error in Flutter side and I want to throw the same error in JS side, How can I do It?
NOTE: currently I am just able to return a string which is not able to throw error.
My example code :
webviewController.addJavaScriptHandler(
handlerName: 'exampleEvent',
callback: (args) {
    try {
        // Do something ...
      } catch (e) {
        // Throw error in JS side 
      }
});

